# How do I store an input file name

Tags: java, swing, input

I am using the code below to read a file into my document (the file will always be different). Anyway is it possible to call the file name so I could at the end of running the code print what the file was called.

Here is the code I am using to read in a file.

```
    // Creates File Chooser and Scans Selected file.
    Scanner input = null;
    File selectedFile = null;
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        input = new Scanner(selectedFile);
    }
```

Thanks in advance and if you need any more information just ask :)

Comment: Sure. Save the value somewhere

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem, but maybe the method you're looking for is [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName()):

```
String filename = selectedFile.getName();
```

If you still have access to that `File` object, then you have its name.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for JFileChooser over [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html).

A quick search on the page reveals the method [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getName(java.io.File)), which does what you want.